# UIPageControl skips over page when swiped?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

Currently I have a UIPageController and it appears to be skipping over a screen when swiped. It's strange because I put print line statements in for when a VC is in use and it looks like it moves to the right VC before quickly going to the next VC in the same swipe. (ie. goes to step2 and then goes to step3 but during the same swipe) Here is how it's set up:

```
     var maxPages : Int!
     var currentIndex : Int = 0
     var  listOfViews = ["step1", "step2", "step3", "step4"]


//maxPages = listOfViews.count in viewDidLoad
        public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        var index : Int = (viewController.view as? BGMWelcomePageView)!.index

        index += 1

        if (index == maxPages)
        {
            index = 0
        }


        return self.getViewControllerWithImage(index)
    }

    public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        var index : Int = (viewController.view as? BGMWelcomePageView)!.index

        index -= 1

        if (index < 0)
        {
            index = maxPages - 1
        }

//This is the function called to get the corresponding view controller
   func getViewControllerWithImage(_ index: Int) -> UIViewController
    {

        var vc : UIViewController
        let loopCount = 999//(index < self.maxPages - 1) ? 1 : 99
        switch listOfViews[index] {
        case "step1":
            vc =  self.buildViewControllerWithImage(titleString: "FIRST_SCREEN_TITLE".localized, descriptionString: "FIRST_SCREEN_DESCRIPTION".localized, backgroundImage: "fractal_blue", jsonFile: "Welcome_Step_01_V01", index: index, loopCount: loopCount)
             print("XXXX Current listView: step1 XXXX")
        case "step2":
            vc =  self.buildViewControllerWithImage(titleString: "SECOND_SCREEN_TITLE".localized, descriptionString: "SECOND_SCREEN_DESCRIPTION".localized, backgroundImage: "fractal_blue", jsonFile:
                "Welcome_Step_02_V01", index: index, loopCount: loopCount)
            print("XXXX Current listView: step2 XXXXX")

        case "step3":
            vc =  self.buildViewControllerWithImage(titleString: "THIRD_SCREEN_TITLE".localized, descriptionString: "THIRD_SCREEN_DESCRIPTION".localized, backgroundImage: "fractal_blue", jsonFile: "Welcome_Step_03_V01", index: index, loopCount: loopCount)
            print("XXXXX Current listView: step3 XXXXXX")

        case "step4":
            vc =  self.buildViewControllerWithImage(titleString: "FOURTH_SCREEN_TITLE".localized, descriptionString: "FOURTH_SCREEN_DESCRIPTION".localized, backgroundImage: "fractal_blue", jsonFile: "Welcome_Step_04_V01", index: index, loopCount: loopCount)
            print("XXXXXX Current listView: step4 XXXXXX")

        default:
            vc =  self.buildViewControllerWithImage(titleString: "FIRST_SCREEN_TITLE".localized, descriptionString: "", backgroundImage: "fractal_blue", jsonFile: "Welcome_Step_01_V01", index: index, loopCount: loopCount)
                print("XXXXX Current listView: default XXXXXX")
        }
        self.currentIndex = index

    //print("XXXXX Current Index: \(self.currentIndex) XXXXXXX")
        return vc
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing a few lines... Regardless, I cringe when I see people trying to keep track of an index themselves. You're modifying the index in both the before and after. Also, a page view controller is intended to page through viewControllers, not views. If you have a list of ViewControllers you can use "myViewControllerList.index(of: UIViewController)" to get the index you're looking for without all the track it yourself mumbo-jumbo

Comment: using viewControllers with pageController should I comment my demo code for you. ? tested and working for me